# Need to find product details with minimum price

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 tbl_product:                             
+------+------+------------+-------+     
| id   | code | name  |brand|origin|
+------+------+------------+-------+
|    1 | 1001 | apple | X   | a    |
|    2 | 1002 | mango | V   | b    |
|    3 | 1003 | banana| Z   | a    |
+------+------+------------+-------+
tbl_product_price:
+------+------+------+
| id   | code | price|
+------+------+------+
|    1 | 1001 |  250 |
|    2 | 1001 |  220 | 
|    3 | 1002 |  175 |
|    4 | 1002 |  180 |
|    5 | 1003 |  170 |
|    6 | 1003 |  190 |  
+------+------+------+
```

I have a search box and if i select any pro

SELECT a.id, a.pro_code, a.pro_unit, MIN(b.pro_price) FROM tab_product a INNER JOIN tab_product_price b  WHERE pro_code like('" .$search . "%') ORDER BY pro_code LIMIT 5"
  But no pro_code display in SEARCH box.

Please this code is ok!!

Answer (score 5):

First thing to do is to `JOIN` the two tables since `Price` of the product belong to `tbl_product_price`. After joining, you need to use an aggregate function `MIN()` and a `GROUP BY` to get the lowest price in every group.

```
SELECT  a.id, a.code, a.name, MIN(b.Price) minimumPrice
FROM    tbl_product a
        INNER JOIN tbl_product_price b
            ON a.code = b.code
GROUP   BY a.id, a.code, a.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b8901/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║ CODE ║  NAME  ║ MINIMUMPRICE ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ 1001 ║ apple  ║          220 ║
║  2 ║ 1002 ║ mango  ║          175 ║
║  3 ║ 1003 ║ banana ║          170 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY a.id, a.code, a.name ? Only group by a.code will work ? Isn't it ?

Comment: @Vivek yes it will work for `MySQL` not on any other RDBMS. For me, it is a bad practice.

Comment: Why will it not work for any other RDBMS ? What is the technical reason/logic behind it ?

Comment: @Vivek see here in sql server http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26a29/2. it is needed to list all non aggregated column in the `select` statement on the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MySQL [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)s, [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) functions:

```
SELECT
    `id`, `a`.`code`, `name`, IFNULL(MIN(`price`), 'no min price') as `minimum_price`
FROM
    `tbl_product` `a` LEFT JOIN `tbl_product_price` `b` ON `a`.`code` = `b`.`code`
GROUP BY
    `id`, `a`.`code`, `name`;
```

This also works, if you have product with no prices specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tbl_product.id, tbl_product.code, tbl_product.name, MIN(tbl_product_price.Price) minimumPrice
FROM    tbl_product,tbl_product_price
        Where tbl_product.code = tbl_product_price.code
GROUP BY  tbl_product.code
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b8901/10)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little puzzled that none of the previous respondents thought to provide the 'standard' answer to this problem, but perhaps that's because it's covered in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html). The 'uncorrelated subquery' version of this query provides a more robust answer and, performance-wise, will trump those thus far provided.